# Stack overflow error importing data to Microsoft Power BI: 'Evaluation resulted in a stack overflow and cannot continue.'

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, twinfield, invantive-bridge

When trying to import data from a database into Power BI (using the Invantive Bridge ADO.net provider) I get an error:

`Expression.Error: Evaluation resulted in a stack overflow and cannot continue.`

[image: Power BI stack overflow Error]

I like to know why I get this error. Is there a way to find out where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with Power BI not parsing the exceptions well.

You can find the actual error message by performing the following steps:

1. From the Query Editor dialog or the main screen, go to *File* > *Options and settings* > *Options*.

   [image: dialog 1]
2. Go to *Diagnostics* and check *Enable tracing*. Click on *Open traces folder*. Dismiss the dialog by click on *OK*.

   [image: dialog 2]
3. Explorer opens with a path similar to `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\Traces`. Go back to Power BI and click on *Refresh* in the ribbon.
4. Power BI generates several log files in the folder previously opened. Open the file starting with `Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40`. This is the log file containing the actual error messages.
5. Find the latest error message. Usually you can find that by searching for `ValidationException` from bottom to top.

   Sample:

   ```
   itgeneor028: Unknown table projjects ( Possible alternatives: (Projects, ProjectWBS)
      at Invantive.Data.ValidationException..ctor(String messageCode, String messageText, String kindRequest, String localStackTrace, String nk, Exception innerException)
   ```

   As you can see, this error was caused by a typo in the table name.

Comment: It seems that May 2017 releases or newer of Power BI raise a stack overflow exception a whole lot less often.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman cannot locate `Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40` or `ValidationException` in 2021 Excel 365 Power Query. Can you or anyone help?